# Using Listlast in CF where values have commas

Tags: coldfusion, cfml

I have the following variable:

```
<cfset last = listlast(GedData.Location)>
```

GetData is a query output, and Location is one of the fields.  The goal is to get the last item in the list.

My problem is that Location carries with it commas; such as: `"Washington, Sullivan County, NH 03280", "Mount Washington, Coos County, NH 03589"`

Currently the value of last is  `NH 03589`.  How do I get last to equal `Mount Washington, Coos County, NH 03589`

Thanks.

Comment: Not related to your question, but unless you use the value list function, you are only going to get data from the first record returned by your query.

Comment: Storing "lists" of data is notoriously problematic. What is the source of the query? Is it a database you control?

Comment: Your problem is not so much that it is difficult to get the data you want, rather, the problem is that the data is returned in a less than optimal format. I would suggest, if possible, you rework how the data is returned.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to provide `"` as a delimiter to `listLast()`. Like this.

```
<cfset last = listlast(GedData.Location,'"')>
```

Comment: simple answer to a difficult problem.Thanks much